# Can't Detect Object with a Specific Color (RGB/HSV/HSL)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

My aim is to detect the lanes on GTA Vice City. [image: gtares2.jpg]

When I analyse this picture on paint, the lines are like [120,100,45] in RGB color space. When I apply this with cv2.inRange, I can't get result strangely. I do not know what to do and do not know why it didn't show me any signs of this yellow (actually it looks like yellow) lanes.

edit1:

I find the values to obtain only these lines, they are:
lower: 0,110,0
upper: 160,195,80

And here's the photo of it, [image: stack2.png]

However, when I tried to obtain this line on live playing, with ImageGrab module (after canny and gaussblur), I get:

[image: stackoverflow.png]

My aim is to draw lane with HoughProbabilistic, however, I can't see continuous lines, even there is no line every time on live playing. I'm confused, here's the codes:

```
   def process_img(image):
    lower_yellow = np.array([0, 110, 0])
    upper_yellow = np.array([160, 195, 80])
    # yellow color mask
    processimagehsl = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(processimagehsl, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)  # and we are masking it
    masked = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=yellow_mask)  # and then we combine it with original image
    # turned into gray
    processimagecanny = cv2.Canny(masked, threshold1=150,
                                  threshold2=300)  # with canny edge detection method, we detect edges
    # of only our yellow lines' edges. We used masking
    # at the beginning of the code because of this.
    processimagegauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(processimagecanny, (5, 5), 0)  # This'Ll fix some in order to avoid noises
    processedimage = regionofinterest(processimagegauss)  # Let's get back to our predetermined region
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(processedimage, 1, np.pi / 180, 180, 0, 0)

    return processedimage
```

---

#### Solved

You can pick the range with this application on OpenCv, here's the link: http://answers.opencv.org/question/134248/how-to-define-the-lower-and-upper-range-of-a-color/

And here's what it looks like with explanation:

[image: imagepick.png]

Comment: can you paste your code and the output which you are getting

Comment: opencv uses BGR by default so try a range around [45, 100, 120] or convert from BGR to RGB.

Comment: Micka I tried it, no solution of that

Comment: @v.coder Please help guys, I updated, lil' bit urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fifth argument `lines` in [`cv2.HoughLinesP()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlinesp). The positional arguments expect the order:

```
cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold[, lines[, minLineLength[, maxLineGap]]])
```

You can solve this one of two ways; either use `None` where the argument is expected for `lines`:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold, None, minLineLength, maxLineGap)
```

or call all the optional arguments you *want* to use with their key:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold=..., minLineLength=..., maxLineGap=...)
```

Comment: Well, I got the point. Thanks, Love SoF Because of you and the others like you